# req value is undefinded in node js and pug

Tags: javascript, html, node.js

I am using pug to generate a form as follows: 
person.pug

```
html
head
   title Person
   body
      form(action = "/person", method = "POST")
      div
     label(for = "name") Name: 
     input(name = "name")
  br
  div
     label(for = "age") Age: 
     input(name = "age")
  br
  div
     label(for = "nationality") Nationality: 
     input(name = "nationality")
  br
  button(type = "submit") Create new person
```

and in server side I am trying to handle the request by a post method: method:

```
app.post('/person', function(req, res){
var personInfo = req.body; //Get the parsed information
console.log(req.body);
if(req.body == null) {
    res.render('show_message', {
        message: "Sorry, you provided worng info", type: "error"});
} else {
    if(!personInfo.name || !personInfo.age || !personInfo.nationality){
    res.render('show_message', {
        message: "Sorry, you provided worng info", type: "error"});
    } else {
    var newPerson = new Person({
        name: personInfo.name,
        age: personInfo.age,
        nationality: personInfo.nationality
    });

    newPerson.save(function(err, Person){
        if(err)
            res.render('show_message', {message: "Database error", type: "error"});
        else
            res.render('show_message', {
                message: "New person added", type: "success", person: personInfo});
    });
    }
}
 });
```

When I run the request the req.body is always null (notdefiend).

Comment: Do you have any body-parsing middleware? See [the documentation](https://expressjs.com/en/api.html#req.body)

Comment: Side note: `null` is not "notdefined" (nor is `undefined`). `req.body` is `undefined`, not "not defined" and not `null`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`req.body` is not filled in by default. As it says in [the documentation](http://expressjs.com/en/4x/api.html#req.body):

> **req.body**
>
> Contains key-value pairs of data submitted in the request body. **By default, it is `undefined`**, and is populated when you use body-parsing middleware such as [body-parser](https://www.npmjs.org/package/body-parser) and [multer](https://www.npmjs.org/package/multer).

*(my emphasis)*